# How to copy value of a module in another module [ODOO]

Tags: python, module, copy, odoo

I made a custom subscription module

subscription.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class subscriptions(osv.osv):
    _name = "subscriptions.sub"
    _description = "subscriptions"

    _columns = {
        'sub_id': fields.integer('Subscription ID', size=10),
        'cust_id': fields.many2one('res.partner','customer_id', 'Customer ID')
     }
```

partner.py

```
from openerp import fields, models

class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    customer_id = fields.Integer('Customer ID'),
    subscription_id =  fields.One2many('subscriptions.sub', 'sub_id', 'Subscription ID')
```

When I create subscriptions from my customer module it also shows in the subscription module, but when I create a subscription in my subscription module it doesn't show in the customer module.

Could I get some help in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean "partner module"?  There's no customer module shown.

Comment: yes, I mean the customer form which is using the partner module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is about understanding the arguments passed to Many2one and One2many fields.

## For Many2one

In the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html), the following is currently stated:

> **`class openerp.fields.Many2one(comodel_name=None, string=None, **kwargs)`**
>
> The value of such a field is a recordset of size 0 (no record) or 1 (a single record).
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `comodel_name` -- name of the target model (string)
> - `auto_join` -- whether JOINs are generated upon search through that field (boolean, by default `False`)
>
> The attribute `comodel_name` is mandatory except in the case of related fields or field extensions.

So, the second parameter of a `fields.Many2one` is the name the field will have in the interface. And in the old API we can see ([in openerp/osv/fields.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1bb61c970ed63eabe3821d21f3ed6f99c4b16daa/openerp/osv/fields.py#L723)) that the third argument is an `auto_join` flag:

```
class many2one(_column):              
    # ...
    def __init__(self, obj, string='unknown', auto_join=False, **args):
```

Thus, in your given example you should remove the second argument and only have two arguments when specifying the many2one.

## For One2many

For One2many, the documentation states:

> **`class openerp.fields.One2many(comodel_name=None, inverse_name=None, string=None, **kwargs)`**
>
> One2many field; the value of such a field is the recordset of all the records in `comodel_name` such that the field `inverse_name` is equal to the current record.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `comodel_name` -- name of the target model (string)
> - `inverse_name` -- name of the inverse `Many2one` field in `comodel_name` (string)
>
> The attributes `comodel_name` and `inverse_name` are mandatory except in the case of related fields or field extensions.

So in this case you are right that a second argument is needed, but the one you choose (`sub_id`) is wrong. For the `inverse_name` you have to choose a `Many2one` field on the `comodel_name` which will point back to the model with the `One2many`. Hence in your instance the `inverse_name` should be `cust_id`.

## Conclusion

To establish a relationship from a `Many2one` field of a model, toward a `One2many` field of another model, the `inverse_name` of the `One2many` field must be the technical name of that `Many2One` field, for example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.a'
    m2o_model_a = fields.Many2one('model.a')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.b'
    # inverse_name is set to the Many2one of ModelA which points to ModelB
    o2m_model_a = fields.One2many('model.b', 'm2o_model_a')
```

When your code doesn't follow this, a link is not established between the two fields, and you will have for each model field independent values.

Comment: Thorough answer. I toned down the formatting slightly.  Also for your reference, if there's a language tag on a question, that question and its answers get the syntax highlighting for that language automatically. (So in this case you get python highlighting for free. :) )

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. It's working now